# Getting connection refused errors when doing mvn clean install

Tags: redquerybuilder

I downloaded the Tardis branch of RedQueryBuilder and did an mvn clean install.

It runs through things for a bit then it gets to this part

[INFO] Running com.redspr.redquerybuilder.core.client.GwtTestDom
[INFO] logging for HtmlUnit thread
[INFO]    [ERROR] I/O error on HTTP request
[INFO] org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://50.19.99.237:53655 refused

Just wondering if there's a quick answer, like, oh your gwt is out of date, or some such other easy to solve issue.

Comment: Tried this build on a different machine and it ran without errors, looks like it has something to do w/ my gwt install, maybe it has to do with also having the gae installed.  Will try to figure out what's different between the two environments, then post the results.

Comment: Grrr. Has to be a longer comment.... Any luck?

Comment: Not yet, not sure where it's coming from in the build.  I removed GAE and still getting the error.  It builds fine on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

So here was the problem, had nothing to do with GAE.

The problem was that the name of my host, in /etc/hostname,  had no corresponding host entry in /etc/hosts.  It was complicated by the fact that I had "search mydomain.com" in my resolv.conf, which was further complicated by the fact that mydomain.com is wildcarded, so any unknown hostnames resolve to a particular IP address.

So what happend was, the test suite would look for myhost, since it didn't find myhost in DNS or in /etc/hosts, it looked up myhost.mydomain.com, as a result of my resolv.conf, which returned a valid IP address, because of the wildcard.  Then the test suite got a connection refused, because it was connecting to a totally different host.  So the solution was to add 127.0.0.1 myhost myhost.mydomain.com to my /etc/hosts and it built and ran fine.

Long story short, if the host defined in /etc/hostname does not have a valid DNS or /etc/hosts entry, the build will fail,  as it will either get a host unknown, or in my case a connection refused because of my DNS jiggery pokery.